# How to make for-loop to neglect several columns and do rbind all sheets (regardless the total amount of sheets) in an excel file

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to do several orders in a for-loop which are

1. neglect the first row below column
2. change all column name to lowercase and eliminate all spaces between words(if there are any)
3. neglect several columns and keep the rest
4. do rbind for all sheets in the excel file

I already did this

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(reshape2)
setwd("D:/Plan")
file<-"Plan.xlsx"
excel_sheets(file)
sheet=excel_sheets(file)

for (i in 1:1) {
    file=read_excel(file, sheet=sheet[i])
    file<-file[-1,]
    judul=colnames(file)
    judul=tolower(judul)
    judul=gsub(' ','',judul)
    colnames(file)=judul
    file %>% filter(!is.na(promo))
    file=file %>% filter(!is.na(promo))
    data=file[,names(file) %in% c("promo","startdate","enddate","sku","marketplacename","diskon","stok")]
}

out=data

for (i in 2:2) {
    file=read_excel(file, sheet=sheet[i])
    file<-file[-1,]
    judul=colnames(file)
    judul=tolower(judul)
    judul=gsub(' ','',judul)
    colnames(file)=judul
    file %>% filter(!is.na(promo))
    file=file %>% filter(!is.na(promo))
    data=file[,names(file) %in% c("promo","startdate","enddate","sku","marketplacename","diskon","stok")]
    x<-data
    out=rbind(out,x)
}
```

this code is just an example of a file excel with 2 sheets. The real one is a file with several sheets, but I want to do those orders regardless the amount of sheets, so I don't edit the script everytime I find a different amount of sheets in file. How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do `length(excel_sheet(filename))` and loop from `1`to this number? Then save the result in a list and rbind it outside the loop.

Comment: how to do it? 
x<-length(sheet) ?

Comment: I made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, where I iterate directly over the sheet names rather than using indices. There's no guarantee that this code will work directly, since you haven't given us any example data to test. Nevertheless, it should point you in the right direction, and probably will work with some minor tweaking:

```r
library(readxl)
library(stringr) # Needed for `str_*` functions.
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr) # Needed for `set_colnames`.

file_name <- "Plan.xlsx"
sheets <- excel_sheets(file_name)
df_final <- tibble()

for (sheet in sheets){
    df_final <- read_excel(file_name, sheet = sheet) %>%
        select(-1) %>% 
        set_colnames(str_remove_all(names(.), "\\s") %>% str_to_lower()) %>%  
        filter(!is.na(promo)) %>%
        select(promo, startdate, enddate, sku, marketplacename, diskon, stok) %>% 
        bind_rows(df_final, .)
}
```

The  `stringr` functions aren't absolutely necessary. I find the naming conventions useful when interpreting my code later, but you can stick with `gsub` and `tolower` if you prefer them instead. You can shorten things if your selected columns are consecutive, i.e. you could do `promo:stok` if all the other columns you want are between those two. The function `set_colnames` comes from `magrittr` and offers a terse, chainable alternative to `colnames(df) <- some_names`. The rest resembles you code more or less, it's just been cleaned up a bit.

Comment: what is tibble() function for?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto the `tibble` function creates a special type of dataframe, and with `df_final <- tibble()` I'm just creating an empty dataframe.